# Check Wallpaper programmatically in android?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

Our android devices Home Screen contains Wallpaper or Live-Wallpaper. How do check through programmatically the Wallpaper is Live-Wallpaper or not.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Your answers are valuable me. Please reply your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

WallpaperInfo wi=wm.getWallpaperInfo();
```

Using these two classes you may get the information.

Comment: Can you explain in detailed... How do check?

Comment: i show this classes first time so i dont have much idea... but using WallpaperInfo class...there is lots of method of this class... just try and print it one by one so we can get some data about the wallpaper...

Comment: And can I somehow change the wallpaper programmatically? Can you please check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-on-rooted-device-android